# Nullpointerexception on getIntent()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I want to get a value from my second activity to use it in a separate class (a fragmentPageAdapter). At first this value is passed from my main activity to my second activity using Intent.putExtra(key_name, string). So in my second activity I am retrieving this value again with getIntent().getStringExtra(key_name). However I want to use this specific value not inside my second activity but in my fragmentPageAdapter which is a separate class. So I thought I use an getter inside my second activity so that I can retrieve this value in my fragmetnPageAdapter class. However I'll get an nullpointerexception.

Inside my second activity I am using this getter:

```
public String getMyItem(){
    return getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem");
}
```

this is how my fragmentPageAdapter class looks like:

```
class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
MySecondActivity mySecondActivity = new MySecondActivity();
public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(mySecondActivity.getMyItem().equals("ride_height")){
        if(i==0){
            fragment = new fragment_ride_height_overview();
        }
        if(i==1){
            fragment = new fragment_ride_height_measure();
        }
        if(i==2){
            fragment = new fragment_ride_height_adjust();
        }
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3; //nothing implemented here yet...
}
```

}

the nullpointerexception looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.offroad_set_up_guide.MySecondActivity.getMyItem(MySecondActivity.java:73)
        at com.example.offroad_set_up_guide.myPagerAdapter.getItem(MySecondActivity.java:86)
```

Now the weird thing is, if I change the getter to the code below, it does work as I expect.

```
public String getMyItem(){
    return "ride_height";
}
```

So I thought something is going wrong with retrieving the data  of the "selectedItem". So I did use the Toast annotation (could have used the log function I suppose...) function to print out the: getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem"). And whenever this is printed on the screen I'll do get a string with a value of "ride_height". Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here, would really appreciate it :).

NOTE: 
Ignore the bad use of if statements inside the public Fragment getItem() function, this was wrote this way just for the sake of testing.

EDIT:

I think I did not clarify my question enough. This is my full code:

```
 public class MySecondActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_2);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            List<String> tabNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            tabNames.addAll(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tabNames"));
            for (String tabName : tabNames) {
               actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                                         .setText(tabName)
                                         .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    public String getMyItem(){
        return getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem");
        //return "ride_height";
    }
}

class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    MySecondActivity mySecondActivity = new MySecondActivity();
    public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(mySecondActivity.getMyItem().equals("ride_height")){
            if(i==0){
                fragment = new fragment_ride_height_overview();
            }
            if(i==1){
                fragment = new fragment_ride_height_measure();
            }
            if(i==2){
                fragment = new fragment_ride_height_adjust();
            }
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3; //nothing implemented here yet...
    }
}
```

MySecondActivity is started by my main activity (with a listview listener) with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext() , MySecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedItem", "ride_height");
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("tabNames", tabNames.get(i).getTabNames());
            startActivity(intent);
```

I just don't understand why I get an return getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem");. Hope this will clarify it a bit for you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MySecondActivity mySecondActivity = new MySecondActivity();
```

`getIntent` returns the intent used to start the Activity, and it is never null, but when you try to instantiate the `Activity` with the new operator. You should never deal directly with Acitivity object, and you should always rely on the framework (take a look to the activity's lifecycle).

Edit

You could add a second parameter to the adapter constructor

```
class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String mItem;
    public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String item) {
        super(fm);
        mItem = item;
    }
```

and inside `getItem`

```
if("ride_height".equals(mItem)) {
```

and inside onCreate

```
new myPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem"))
```

Please be aware that making your adapter returning null will probably make your application crash

Comment: You should always use `startActivity()` or related, never create an Activity object, as blackbelt correctly pointed out !

Comment: Indeed, this is only the first of many ways in such a create-it-yourself Activity instance will malfunction.

Comment: Your edit still does this incorrectly. You can't call `new Activity`.

Comment: Ok I understand that I can't call a new activity, but how can I access the getMyItem method from myPageAdapter class otherwise? I'm still quite new to Android and Java, so excuse me for the silly mistakes.